# PCB design - Routing without a schematic

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I am using Altium CircuitMaker to design a PCB. I'm wondering if there's a way to make my PCB design without a schematic.

My idea is to simply make a PCB with just pads and populate it myself with the required components. For instance, right now I have set up some pads in the PCB for me to insert header pins into and solder and then I am planning to attach the PCB onto an Arduino Mega (as shown in the image.)

[image]

When I try to do some routing, it doesn't allow me to route pads. I did some research and I believe this is because I'm not using a schematic so I have no assigned nets. I'm guessing you cannot route without pre-assigning nets in your schematic. Is there a way around this or do I have to use actual components such as header connectors in the schematic, then assign nets and route?

Comment: Can't you use test points or similar schematic symbols?

Comment: There might be a way but you will be skipping a step so basically doing it wrong. If you do it like that, and the PCB has a problem, you have no schematic (or the blueprint, or the plan, whatever word fits) to show to anyone, to verify if the connections are right or wrong. The correct way to do it is of course to make a schematic and see that the logical connections are correct, and then move on to designing the physical connections in the form of PCB design, and the schematic connections will warn if the PCB connections are not properly made for example.

Comment: @Lundin How do test points work? I'm quite new to this sorry. I'm just wondering if I can assign a net to the pads in the PCB diagram instead of using a schematic with components + nets? If not, I think I will do as you said by using similar schematic symbols.

Comment: @Justme That is true. If I decide to go about it that way which I have tried before, what would I do for example, when I need something like a single header pin? On Altium CircuitMaker, there aren't really any symbols for a single header pin.

Comment: @Vagabond4761 For what you need a single header pin? Put the correct connector there to begin with, there are likely footprints for mounting an Arduino, complete with pin numbers and names.

Comment: @Justme Firstly, I am not using all the pins on the Arduino for my circuit. This is why in the image, I only have the 10-12, 30-31, 3.3V and 5V pads set up for the pins I'm going to use. from the Arduino. So, I would just set up male headers there in my PCB to mount onto the respective female headers that's currently on the Arduino Mega. Secondly, the single header pin is used because I have a LCD display that I want to mount ontop of the PCB and it has 20 pins (and again I'm not using all of them).

Comment: @Justme Since I'm only using like 8 of the pins from the LCD, there's an awkward pin that has no neighbours which is why I would need a single header.

Comment: @Vagabond4761 And you are omitting them because why? What difference it makes if the PCB has pins for all Arduino pins, and then you use the ones you need? You can even solder only the pins you need, but frankly, it's simpler to just attach the whole row of pinheader, for mechanical stability, and you likely benefit from multiple ground pins etc.

Comment: @Justme I see what you mean. You're right, there is no difference. I could just use all the pins to mount it. I'm guessing same logic with the LCD pins then, I can just set up a row of 20 headers and not use some. Unless you know any other ways to get a single header?

Comment: A test point is typically just a circle of exposed copper with a given designator. Schematic editors tend to treat them similar to connectors.

Comment: There are prototyping boards out there. Also, breadboards and breakouts for various MCU modules. Something like this: https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Mikroe/MIKROE-767?qs=M1T3mF8ombWAHzmDq6PF3Q%3D%3D

Comment: You may be able to route a board without a schematic if you turn off Design Rule Checking.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the correct way is to create the schematic for it.

If, for any reason, you want to do it in the PCB, you can do it by setting the net names.
First, you need to create the net. From the Design option, select the following:

```
Design->Netlist->Edit Nets
```

Then select "Add". From the window, set the net name you want. I've used "Net1" for example. Press OK to create the net.

[image: Add net]

Add as many separate nets as you need.

Now, you have a net to assign to pads. Select the pad and open the properties window for it (or simply double-click on the pad to open the properties). In this window, there is a "Net Name" field. For example, in the following image, the net name is set to "Net1".

[image: Assign net]

Then repeat this process for the other pad that you want to be connected to this pad. By setting the same net names for pads, Altium will connect them together. Then you can use the routing tool to draw the track.

[image: Routing]

Comment: When I double click on the pad, it comes up with a similar thing as what is shown in your image. However, I don't have a net information block so I can't see a "Net name" field. I do have the properties block and for the "Net" field, for me it says No Net. I tried to change that but it doesn't let me.

Comment: You need to create the netlabel first. I don't have Altium on this computer. I remove the answer, later on, I'll create screenshots of the whole process and put them here.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to find a computer with the Altium on it. I hope it's still useful.